# RQDA - Export categories per file in a project

Tags: sql, r, rqda

I have coded a number of texts in RQDA and I am trying to export the categories in a database. I would be looking as an final result to be a Data Frame something like this:

```
Files   Categories
File1   Category1
File2   Category2
File3   Category3
File4   Category2
File5   Category1
```

I tried the following code which I have adapted from here [Rblogger](https://www.r-bloggers.com/qualitative-data-science-using-rqda-to-analyse-interviews/):

```
categories <- RQDAQuery("select filecat.name as category, source.name as filename 
                         from treefile, filecat, source 
                         where treefile.catid=filecat.catid and treefile.fid=source.id and treefile.status=1")
```

But it has resulted in an empty file so far:

```
str(categories)
'data.frame':   0 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ category: chr 
 $ filename: chr 

> dim(categories)
[1] 0 2
> summarise(categories)
data frame with 0 columns and 1 row
```

Any help is welcome.

Comment: Obviously, query returns zero results and actually that SQL is the older version of  the `INNER JOIN` query. Please show sample of *treefile*, *filecat*, *source* tables/data.

Comment: Thank you. I am not very sure how shall I get this information. Would you help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some friend in an old email list was kind enough to help me, so here goes the answer:

```
codings <-RQDAQuery("select s.name as 'filename', f.name as 'codes' from source s, 
                   coding c, 
                   freecode f where s.id = c.fid and c.cid = f.id and s.status = 1 order by s.name")

categories <- RQDAQuery("select s.name as 'filename', 
                    co.name as 'categories' from source s, 
                    coding c, freecode f, codecat co, 
                    treecode tr where s.id = 
                    c.fid and c.cid = f.id and co.catid = 
                    tr.catid and tr.cid = f.id and s.status = 1 and c.status = 1 and 
                    f.status = 1 order by s.name")
```

All the best

Comment: Consider not using [implicit joins but explicit joins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44917/explicit-vs-implicit-sql-joins) with `INNER JOIN` for readability and maintainability. Also, for SO answers please explain in words the solution for future readers and what was the issue in original problem.